# systemctl .service can't read the environment variable

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables, django, uwsgi

I'm using django and now trying to configure server with nginx and uwsi. now i'm running nginx+socket+uwsgi_emperor well . for running uwsgi i use below command in terminal:

```
 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

and it's working great. now i want add service with `systemctl {start|stop|restart|status} uwsgi.service` so i can easily use uwsgi. the problem here occur.here is /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
# i'm putting code same code of terminal exactly here:
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
# Requires systemd version 211 or newer
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now when i start it with `systemctl start uwsgi.service` its running and i can see `systemctl status uwsgi.service` thaat is loaded well but when i want access the ip the error appear in `journalctl -b -u uwsgi` that shown my django can't access(read) the environment variable.because i using several environment variable in django's setting so without value of them django can't work correctly.why this happen?(when i running uwsgi in command line  all is good but when i want use same command in systemctl django can't read environment variable and error occur ). thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> that shown my django can't access(read) the environment variable

Because systemd is not running in a shell with your user and that user environment and those variables.

> when i running uwsgi in command line

then you are using your own user with that environment and those variables.

---

You need a

```
EnvironmentFile=/dir/to/file
```

before your `ExecStart`. Or if it is not that many you can also do

```
Environment={VAR}={VALUE}
```

(one line per variable) where

- {VAR} is the name of your environment variable
- {VALUE} is the value of that {VAR}

Answer (score 1):

One other approach in addition to the accepted answer is to have this `/bin/bash -lc '<your command>'` for your ExecStart or ExecStop

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'yarn start'
```

and have a corresponding `/etc/profile` file with the environment variables.